# Why windows 8.1 64 bit install programs only in 32 bit?

Tags: windows-8.1, 64-bit, 32-bit

basically I have a windows 8.1 64 bit but when i download a software (e.g. firefox) it´s installed automatically in 32 bit, why and how can i change it ?

Comment: There isn't an official non-preview release of a 64-bit Firefox client.  Do you have another example, since your example, there isn't actually a 64-bit build offered?

Answer (score 1):

95% of software still written for 32 bits because the only software that **needs** 64 bits are programs capable of using more than 4gb of RAM.  Firefox is only available in 32 bit version, except for a special testing version.

So unless the program needs more that 4gb of RAM the authors are unlikely to update there programs.  The only way you can change it is by calling/emailing/etc the company/author and asking them to produce a 64 bit version.

Comment: Driver software has to be 64bit on a 64bit OS.